# How does col get its value in Ruby Code: Array.new(cells) { |col| PolarCell.new(row, col) }

Tags: ruby

I don't understand one line on the code below:

```
def prepare_grid
    rows = Array.new(@rows) 

    row_height = 1.0 / @rows 
    rows[0] = [ PolarCell.new(0, 0) ] 

    (1...@rows).each do |row|
      radius = row.to_f / @rows 
      circumference = 2 * Math::PI * radius 

      previous_count = rows[row - 1].length
      estimated_cell_width = circumference / previous_count 
      ratio = (estimated_cell_width / row_height).round 

      cells = previous_count * ratio 
      rows[row] = Array.new(cells) { |col| PolarCell.new(row, col) } 
    end

    rows
  end
```

How does col get its value in the line below???

```
rows[row] = Array.new(cells) { |col| PolarCell.new(row, col) }
```

How to translate that to Javascript?

Comment: Doesn't javascript have something like `foofoo.foreach(function(x) { alert(x) });`? That's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

`col` here is the index, you can see it as follows:

```
arr = Array.new(5) { |i| print "#{i} "; i * 2}
# this prints the value of i each iteration:
# => 0 1 2 3 4

print arr
# each iteration returns i * 2 so the array ends up as:
# => [0,2,4,6,8]
```

5 is the length of the array, and the block is called 5 times (because of zero-indexing, you get the values 0 up to 4 passed for `i`).

In Javascript you could do it with a `for` loop, for example:

```
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Array with block parameter. Creating a PolarCell object as many as the number of cells in that row. PolarCell's arguments are `row` and `col`. The `row` parameter comes from each. The `col` parameter is the index of the new array created.

```
# in javascript
for (col = 0; col < cells.length; i++) { 
  PolarCell(row, col)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How does col get its value in the line below???
>
> ```
> rows[row] = Array.new(cells) { |col| PolarCell.new(row, col) }
> ```

This is called a *parameter* and is a very important concept in programming. A parameter is kind of a "hole" that is left in the definition of a subroutine. Then, when you invoke this subroutine, you can "fill" this hole with a concrete value, this value is called an *argument*.

This very similar to functions in mathematics:

In

```
f(x, y) = x + y
```

`x` and `y` correspond to the programming notion of *parameters* and in

```
f(23, 42)
```

`23` and `42` correspond to the programming notion of *arguments*.

So, here `col` is a *parameter* of the block `{ |col| PolarCell.new(row, col) }` and this block will be called `cells` number of times by `Array::new`, passing first `0`, then `1`, then `2`, and so on as an *argument* to the block.

> How to translate that to Javascript?

JavaScript also has the concept of *parameters* and *arguments*. For example, in

```ecmascript
function foo(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

`a` and `b` are the *parameters*, and in

```ecmascript
foo(23, 42);
```

`23` and `42` are the *arguments*.